# jsonPath exclude field

Tags: node.js, jsonpath

I want get the whole object excluding `template` field, no matter the level.
This is my object:

```
{
            sections:
       [
            {
                name: "part1",
                title: "Part I",
                template: "Part I template",
                children: [{
                    name: "1",
                    title: "part1.1",
                    template:"part1.1 template"
                }, {
                    name: "2",
                    title: "part1.2",
                    template:"part1.2 template"
                }]
            },
        {
            name:"part2",
                //...
        }
    ]
 }
```

I tried https://github.com/s3u/JSONPath and https://github.com/dchester/jsonpath I can't figure it out how can I do that.

Comment: if u want u can simply use a recurrsive method instead of using jsonpath